# Excel date recognition

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I recognize that getting excel to import data and recognize it as a date is a common problem. I have searched through many prior posts with answers but haven't found a resolution yet:

Here's what the original data looks like 
[Data as imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEALD.png)

I don't care about the time, the date is the only important information.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Just reformatting as a date (long, short)
2. Text to columns selecting DMY for the first column and breaking the time into a second column
3. I also tried a Find & Replace where I took that first column and replaced all the '-' with new '-' or with '/' both failed
4. Text to columns and separating all pieces into their own columns, I was going to then recombine them to make a date by using a vlookup table to turn the 'Feb' into a 2 (same for other months), and then use the DATE() but for some reason the day is still reading as text, but the year is recognized as a number. With the day as text, this still fails.

This is making me crazy.

For reference: I am in the US. I would like to be able to find a solution that does not involve any VBA code as I am not great at VBA and the person that will need to manage this on a day-to-day basis is new to excel. We've got about 5000 rows, so there's no way we can do this manually

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that Excel expects a space between the time and the AM/PM.  So put one in with this formula:

```
=--REPLACE(A4,LEN(A4)-1,0," ")
```

The `--` turns the text into a number that can be formatted into the proper date time output.

Then format the cell as you want.

[image]